# Using a provider inside another provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am creating an app that relies on socket.io for real-time notifications. There is a listener that gets triggered when a redis message gets published. This redis listener needs to be global and the data shoved into a provider to share it between controllers. So, what I am doing is creating a notifications providers and injecting the socket provider in order to set the listener. But, even though the socke provider is defined the on() is not. Is there a way that I can accomplish this during the app configuration? or am I just shooting in the air here? Thanks

```
var CRM = angular.module('CRM', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
CRM.config(['socketProvider',function(socket) {
    socket.connect();
}]);

CRM.config(['notificationsProvider',function(not) {
    not.listen();
}]);

CRM.provider('socket', function() {
var socket;
return {
    connect: function() {
        // var host = ''; // Production
        var host = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Dev
        socket = io.connect(host);
        var client = {
            clientType: 'Browser',
            registerFor: ['peberry.*']
        };
        socket.emit('register', client);
    },
    $get: function($rootScope) {
        return {
             on: function(event, callback) {
                socket.on(event, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function(event, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(event, data, function() {
                    var args = aguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
});

CRM.provider('notifications',['socketProvider','redisMsgProvider', function(socket, redisMsg) {
var notifications = [];
return {
    listen: function() {
        console.log(socket.on)
        socket.on('redis', function(msg) {
            redisMsg.processRedis(msg);
            var message = redisMsg.getMessage();
            console.log(message);
        });
    },
    $get: function() {
        return {
            getNotifications: function(action) {
                if (notifications.length > 0) {
                    return notifications;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: The code you've written doesnt work ,at least the notifications provider,you should make it clear. in your question. If you need to run code before your application runs it's better to put it in the module.run callback.the module.config callbackis for configuration purposes only(and will be removed in AngularJS V2 anyway)

Comment: Exactly it breaks on the `socket.on()` and that's what I want to resolve

Comment: My point is in IMHO you are misuing the config callback to run code that should be run somewhere else, check the module.run method or decorators instead.

Comment: @mpm How can that be? I am setting my socket io service that need to connect before being used. IMO the connection part its part of configuring the service to be used. Anyways I did try the `run()` approach with no luck as the connect method is hidden at that point. Im at a loss here. I dont think there is a way around setting this services other than at `$rootScope` to be globally accessible smh

Comment: `Anyways I did try the run() approach with no luck as the connect method is hidden at that point. Im at a loss here.` that's exactly why i'm saying what i'm saying your connect method shouldnt be in the provider configuration but in the actual service.You are missusing the configuration service step.